# find if a semantic version is superset of of another version python

Tags: python, python-3.x, semantic-versioning

I have a use case where I have a list of Java maven semantic ranges trying to find the list of versions that I can exclude in my application.

Example:

```
SemVersion1 = "[,1.8.8.1)"
SemVersion2 = "[,1.8.8.2)"
SemVersion3 = "[,1.8.8.3)"
SemVersion4 = "[1.0.0, 1.4.4)"
SemVersion5 = "[,1.3.11),[,1.7.0), [,1.8.0)"
```

How to filter the various `SemVersion` to only keep the one that includes all other versions. In this case, `SemVersion3` will be picked up because it includes all the versions.

Thinking about something like this in python:

```
        output = []
        for a in SemVersions:
            is_redundent = False
            for b in a:
              if affected_versions[a].issuperset(affected_versions[b]):
              is_redundent = True
              break
        if not is_redundent:
          output.append(b)
```

The problem is that I would need to inflate the `SemVersions` to get the `affected_versions`, is there an easier way to do this.

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me - please fix it to be a [mre] and detail what your problem is. We do not see what `affected_versions` is. Why do you compare your semversion-string characterwise - that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. convert your ranges into a more strict notation to eliminate `',1.2.3.4'` and '1.0,2.3.4' (we need exact lower bounds for the last step)
2. convert your strings into actual [Version](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version/#packaging.version.Version) objects for ease of comparisons (you could also do some conversion to numeral tuples but they break on versions containing non-numeric characters)

---

```
from packaging.version import Version
from functools import cmp_to_key
from collections import defaultdict

def adj_lengths(s, c=3):
    """Add missing .0 to a version up to a predefined count '.'-count.
    Example:  '9.0.2' with c == 3 -> '9.0.2.0'"""

    cnt = s.count(".")
    if c>cnt:
        s = s + ".0"*(c-cnt)
    return s


def split_mult(s):
    """Make versions more precise by replacing implicit range starts.
    Uses adj_lengths to add missing .0 to equalize version lengths.
    Handles splitting multiple given ranges as well. 
    Returns iterable.
    Example: '[,1.3.11),[,1.7.0), [,1.8.0)' 
             -> (['0.0.0.0', '1.3.11.0'],['0.0.0.0', '1.7.0.0'], ['0.0.0.0', '1.8.0.0'])"""

    s = s.replace("[,",f"[0,")
    s1 = [ adj_lengths(b) for b in (t.strip("[()] ") for t in s.split(","))]

    yield from [ s1[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s1),2)]


def make_version(l):
    """Transform text-list into Version-tuple."""

    return ( Version(l[0]), Version(l[1]) )
```

Program:

```
vers = ["[,1.8.8.1)",   
        "[,1.8.8.2)",   
        "[,1.8.8.3)",  
        "[1.0.0, 1.4.4)", 
        "[,1.3.11),[,1.7.0), [,1.8.0)"]

# preprocessing to make them nicer
vers2 = []
for tmp in (split_mult(a) for a in vers) :
    vers2.extend( (make_version(k) for k in tmp) )
print(vers2)

# bring into order
vers2.sort()

# use the lower bound as key - append alle upper bounds to a defaultdict(list)  
d = defaultdict(list)
for fr,to in vers2:
    d[fr].append(to)

# simplify lower bound:[list of upper bounds] to (lower bound, max(upper bound list values))
vers3 = [ (k,max(v)) for k,v in d.items()]

# eliminate range that lie inside the 1st elements range
for item in vers3[1:][:]:
    if item[0] >= vers3[0][0] and item[1] <= vers3[0][1]:
        vers3.remove(item)

print(vers3)
```

Output:

```
[(<Version('0.0.0.0')>, <Version('1.8.8.3')>)]
```

---

If you have more then one resulting range you would have to do the last step for every element - not just the first one, f.e. when your data in the last step is like:

```
[(<Version('0.0.0.0')>, <Version('1.8.8.3')>), 
 (<Version('1.0.0.0')>, <Version('2.8.8.3')>), 
 (<Version('1.2.0.0')>, <Version('1.8.8.3')>), ] # last elem inside before-last elem
```

Comment: That's impressive @patrick, thanks very much. one bug I still have is it breaks on versions containing non-numeric characters. e.g `Invalid version: '2.0.20.Final'`. maybe I should use `version.LegacyVersion` ?

Comment: @JauL  I doubt Final is allowed - this shouldbe 0Final or so - please refer to the Version documentation. Ive used it first today as well ;o)

Comment: the code thinks `[2.9.0,2.9.9.2) || [2.8.0,2.8.11.4) || [,2.7.9.6)`  and `[,2.8.11.1) || [2.9.0, 2.9.5)` are not overlapping, tried to fix it but did not find where is this actually happening?

Comment: getting the following output: `[(<Version('0.0.0.0')>, <Version('2.8.11.1')>), (<Version('2.8.0.0')>, <Version('2.8.11.4')>), (<Version('2.9.0.0')>, <Version('2.9.9.2')>)]` so you mentioned that `If you have more then one resulting range you would have to do the last step for every element ` which last step you were refering to?

Comment: @JauL :eleminating included ranges - if your 3rd range is also inside the 1st one, you would need to eleminate it as well